# Xpath to select an element of multiple namespace

Tags: xslt, xpath, namespaces, soapui

I have an API responding at "http://ip/channels/api" which response something like this

```
<Channels resultCount="200" xmlns="urn:web:1.0">
   <Channel id="tv1"/>
   <Channel id="tv2"/>
</Channels>
```

I am struggling to access Channel element using XPath from a different API call using SoapUI tool. If I try to get any channel id within the same http request using:

```
declare namespace ns1='urn:web:1.0';
//ns1:Channels[1]/ns1:Channel[1]/@id
```

I get back correct result as

> tv1

but if I try to get Channel ID from different http request, I have blank response. I am first defining namespace to reach to http://ip/channels/api and then defining another namespace for xmlns="urn:web:1.0" but I don't know the correct syntax to make up this call. Could someone please help to guide me the right way to do this or refer at least the correct term I should be searching for?

Comment: Did you try using `local-name()`? Along the lines of `//*[local-name() = 'Channels']/*[local-name() = 'Channel']/@id`.

Comment: Rahul, can you show the sample xml with multiple namespaces. Your current sample does not show. By the way, what exactly are you trying to do? Retrieve a value from first response and use that value in following request? Please clarify with details ? Edit the question to update.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you've two request. The first one is:

```
<Channels resultCount="200" xmlns="urn:web:1.0">
   <Channel id="tv1"/>
   <Channel id="tv2"/>
</Channels>
```

And the second one:

```
<Channels resultCount="200" xmlns="http://ip/channels/api">
   <Channel id="tv1"/>
   <Channel id="tv2"/>
</Channels>
```

Both has `<Channel>` element but are from a different namespace definition.

So if you want to use a common *XPath* for both in SOAPUI you can use `*` as  a wildcard for namespace elements so you can avoid the namespace definition and access directly the `<Channel>` id attributes despiste how this node is nested on the parent element and which is it namespace. So something like this must work for your case:

```
//*:Channels[1]/*:Channel[1]/@id
```

Comment: Solution1: `//*:Channels[1]/*:Channel[1]/@id`
It didn't work! I think this can only work within the same http request call but not from different request. In my case, I want to make one call within a different Put request.


Solution2: Didn't work either. Please check below how <XPath-expression> I have formed.
declare namespace ns1='http://ip//channels/api';
declare namespace ns2='urn:web:1.0';
//ns1:ns2:Channels[1]/ns1:ns2:Channel[2]/@id
is this correct XPath?

Comment: @R.Rahul I don't know if I understand your requeriment. But you want an XPath to work with two different Xmls which has the same `<Channel>` element but in different namespaces?

Comment: By the way of course `//ns1:ns2:Channels` not work... this is why I purpose you to use `*` as a wildcard for namespaces.

Comment: I have two different Xmls with different structures. What I want is to a way to find out `<Channel>` from 1 request into another. It's easy to find it if I don't have any `xmlns` defined in parent element `<Channels>` as it's working for other. But in above case when I have `xmlns` I am getting empty value for `<Channel>`

Comment: @R.Rahul sorry I don't get you what "to find out <Channel> from 1 request into another"? You want to check if the exactly same `<Channel>` element is present in both XML? By the way... if you use the `*` you get `<Channel>` id attribute from each element despite if its from one namespace or other other or also if there is not namespace at all.

Comment: whats the solution for this ?